# Intermittent div positioning issue

Tags: css, html, position

I am having a rather strange issue with a single div on my site.  When the page first loads, this particular div (id=header_logo in the code below), is about 100px lower than expected. However, when the page is refreshed, the div goes back to where it *should* be, near the top of the page. In fact, Every time the page is refreshed, the div appears in the correct position. Its only when I close the tab/page and reopen, or open for the first time, that the issue occurs.  The issue seems to be isolated to WebKit based browsers like Chrome and Safari. Firefox renders fine, and oddly enough, so does IE.

[Screenshot of the issue when it occurs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B__-lm8689GVNkJOTUNiNUF0eFU/edit?usp=sharing)

Here the HTML

```
<div id="user_bar">
    </div>

    <div id="main_window">

        <div id="header" class=".gradient">
            <div id="header_text">
                <h1>Lab Connect</h1>
                <h3>Lab Resource Aggregator</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="header_logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="./graphics/SS_Comm_labs.png" height="85" width="420" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url('../graphics/tactile_noise.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    /*background-color:#e7e8ed;*/
    font-family:helvetica;
    margin: 0%;
}

#user_bar {
    height:40px;
    background-color:#38393b;

}

#main_window {
    width:1200px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 15px black;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header {
    height: 125px;
    background: #ffc578; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%, #f79422 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffc578), color-stop(100%,#f79422)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#f79422 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#f79422 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffc578 0%,#f79422 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffc578 0%,#f79422 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffc578', endColorstr='#f79422',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header_text {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;

}

h1 {
    margin: 0%;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0%;
}

#header_logo {
    width: 500px;
    height:110px;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: .75px solid #FFA366;
    border-left: .755px solid #FFA366;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 10px #222222 inset;
}

#header_logo img {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I did inspect the element in Chrome when it broke but I did not see anything in computed style that would push it down like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see an issue in Chrome, would you be able to post a screenshot?  Also, might it have anything to do with the main_window div not having a closing tag or was that just an error with the post?

Comment: If you have put the code on www.jsfiddle.net or at least put a printscreen here your problem would have been clearer. 1. Don't define height and width on your html, but on the css. 2. Why are you giving #header_logo both float: right and display: inline-block?

Comment: I have added a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Just a disambiguation: do not confuse these 2 browsers [Chrome vs Chromium](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Chromium_vs_Google_Chrome). Although they are both developed by Google, there are differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats can be a little finicky. I'd recommend using absolute positioning for this task. These css properties will set the header as the positioning container box, and set the header logo to go in the top right of that box.

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}
#header_logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a width for your `#header_text` div, and it is not floated.
When a block-level element is not floated, has content and no specified width, it takes up 100% of the container by default.

So, the solution is to scrap the `display:inline-block` styles (because they aren't affecting anything), to add `float:left` to your `#header_text`, and you're done! Additionnally, you can (but don't have to) specify a width for your `#header_text`.

If you think removing your div from the document flow is a better option, Chad von nau's solution is the way to go.